# Invalid use of incomplete type (chained templated classes)

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I am trying to create a filesystem interface so that my micro controller can interface with an SD card (and I decided to implement all of the File System stuff from the ground up).  The problem is I don't know what file system will be on the card....It could be FAT16, FAT32, NFTS, ext3, ect.

So I created a the following abstract classes: `FileSystem` `File` and `Directory`.  Now that is all fine and dandy but I am on a micro controller so I want to avoid using the `new` operator.

This leads to my creation of the `UnionBase` class (not a very helpful name).  Basically this class holds a union of all of the different derived classes and allows you to convert between them:

```
struct BaseFile_t{
};
struct DerivedA : BaseFile_t{
};
struct DerivedB : BaseFile_t{
};

UnionBase<BaseFile_t,DerivedA,DerivedB> var;   //Can now pass references 
//of this into File system function 
//so that they can modify the right
//Derived type (which can then be
//used as if it is the base type)
```

Now in order to pass this in I have a struct called `FileSystemUnion` or `FSU` for short.  This basically just defines all of the necessary BaseUnion types.

The real problem is that it seems that it might end up being a type if recursive typedef (which I know is not allowed).  Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "prototypeInd/templates/UnionBase.h"
using namespace prototypeInd::templates;

template<class arg,class conv>
struct File{
};
template<class arg,class conv>
struct Directory : public File<arg,conv>{
};
template<class arg,class conv>
struct FS{
    typedef Directory<arg,conv> Directory;
    typedef File<arg,conv> File;
};
template<class arg,class conv>
struct DFile : public virtual File<arg,conv>{
};
template<class arg,class conv>
struct DDirectory : public virtual Directory<arg,conv>, public virtual DFile<arg,conv>{
    void foo(typename conv::Directory::UnionType& d){
    }
};
template<class arg,class conv>
struct DFS : public virtual FS<arg,conv>{
    typedef DFile<arg,conv> File;
    typedef DDirectory<arg,conv> Directory;
};
template<class arg,template<class,class> class fsa,template<class,class> class fsb>
struct FSU{
    typedef UnionBase<FS<arg,FSU>,fsa<arg,FSU>,fsb<arg,FSU> > FS;
    typedef UnionBase<typename ::FS<arg,FSU>::Directory,typename fsa<arg,FSU>::Directory,typename fsb<arg,FSU>::Directory> Directory;
    typedef UnionBase<typename ::FS<arg,FSU>::File,typename fsa<arg,FSU>::File,typename fsb<arg,FSU>::File> File;
};

typedef FSU<int,DFS,DFS> thing;
DDirectory<int,thing> d;



int main(int d,char** thing){

}
```

The error I get is:
`invalid use of incomplete type 'struct DDirectory<int, FSU<int, DFS, DFS> >'`

Here is UnionBase.h (its huge but don't worry all of this is working):

```
#ifndef prototypeInd_templates_UnionBase_h
#define prototypeInd_templates_UnionBase_h
#include <type_traits>

template<class Type, uint64_t time,class First,class... Array>
class IndexOf_{
        static const bool isSame = std::is_same<First,Type>::value;
    public:
        static const uint64_t value = isSame ? time : IndexOf_<Type,time+1,Array...>::value;
};
template<class Type, uint64_t time, class First>
class IndexOf_<Type,time,First>{
    public:
        //static_assert(std::is_same<First,Type>::value,"Not contained in list");
        static const uint64_t value = time;
};
template<class Type,class... Array>
using IndexOf = IndexOf_<Type,0,Array...>;
template<class Target, class First, class... Rest>
class ContainsType{
    public:
    static const bool value = std::is_same<Target, First>::value ? true : ContainsType<Target,Rest...>::value;
};
template<class Target, class First>
class ContainsType<Target,First>{
    public:
    static const bool value = std::is_same<Target, First>::value;
};
//Best is the highes so far while rest is the rest of the list
template <class Best,class First, class... Rest>
class GetMaxSize{
        //typedef typename GetFirstType<Rest...>::value First;
        static const bool FirstBigger = sizeof(First) > sizeof(Best);

    public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<FirstBigger,typename GetMaxSize<First,Rest...>::value,typename GetMaxSize<Best,Rest...>::value >::type value;
};
template<class Best, class First>
class GetMaxSize<Best,First>{
    static const bool FirstBigger = sizeof(First) > sizeof(Best);
    public:
        typedef typename std::conditional<FirstBigger,First,Best >::type value;
};
template<class From,uint16_t index,class UT,class First,class... Array> 
struct cast{
    static void apply(From** t,UT* f){
        if (index == f->GetActive()){
            *t = &((First)(*f));
        }
        else{
            cast<From,index+1,UT,Array...>::apply(t,f);
        }
    }
};
template<class From,uint16_t index,class UT,class First>
struct cast<From,index,UT,First>{
    static void apply(From** t,UT* f){
        if (index == f->GetActive()){
            *t = &((First)(*f));
        }
    }
};


template<class... Values>
class UnionType{
    typedef typename GetMaxSize<Values...>::value internal_t;
    internal_t data;
    uint16_t active;
    public:
    template<class CastFrom, class Dummy = typename std::enable_if<ContainsType<CastFrom,Values...>::value, int>::type >
    UnionType(CastFrom&& d) : data(reinterpret_cast<internal_t&>(d)),active(IndexOf<CastFrom,Values...>::value){
    }
    template<class CastTo, class Condition = typename std::enable_if<ContainsType<CastTo,Values...>::value,int>::type >
    operator CastTo const&() const{
        return reinterpret_cast<const CastTo&>(data);
    }
    uint16_t GetActive() const{
        return active;
    }
    //This one actually uses casting of the active data type
    template<class CastTo, class Condition = typename std::enable_if<!ContainsType<CastTo,Values...>::value,int>::type >
    explicit operator CastTo*() const{
        CastTo temp;
        CastTo* ret = &temp;
        cast<CastTo,0,UnionType,Values...>::apply(&ret,this);
        return ret;
    }
};

namespace prototypeInd{namespace templates{
template<class Base, class Thing>
struct IsPublicBase{
    static const bool value = std::is_base_of<Base,Thing>::value && std::is_convertible<Thing*,Base*>::value;
};
template<class Base, class First, class... Rest>
struct AllInheritFrom{
    static const bool value = IsPublicBase<Base,First>::value ? AllInheritFrom<Base,Rest...>::value : false;
};
template<class Base, class First>
struct AllInheritFrom<Base,First>{
    static const bool value = IsPublicBase<Base,First>::value;
};
template<template<class> class Function,class First,class... Args>
struct AllFullfill{
    static const bool value = Function<First>::value ? AllFullfill<Function,Args...>::value : false;
};
template<template<class> class Function,class First>
struct AllFullfill<Function,First>{
    static const bool value = Function<First>::value;
};
template<class Base, class... Rest>
class UnionBase{
    static_assert(AllInheritFrom<Base,Rest...>::value, "All of the elements of UnionBase must have Base as a public base");
    public:
        typedef UnionType<Rest...> UnionType;
    private:
        UnionType internal;
    public:
        UnionBase() : internal(typename GetFirstType<Rest...>::value()){};

        UnionBase(Base&& value) : internal(value){
        }
        operator UnionType&(){
            return internal;
        }
        Base* operator ->() const{
            //return 0;
            return &((Base&)internal);
        }
};
//template<class Base, class... Rest>
//using UnionBase = UnionBase_<Base,Rest...>*;
}}
#endif
```

So the real question is: what should I do to make this work?  I am open to restructuring a little bit, but after hours of trying everything I can think of I am almost ready to scrap the whole thing and start again.

Comment: After I substituted the missing parts [I couldn't reproduce the error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7eda9b10e09555f). Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @AntonSavin I added a the file....It is very large, but it is all working (I have tested separate from this project.  This should induce the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in certain places of code your classes are really incomplete.

According to [class.mem]/1:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*.
>   Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies,
>   default arguments, *using-declarations* introducing inheriting constructors (12.9), *exception-specifications*, and
>   *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise
>   it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

When applied to your code, this means in particular that the class is incomplete within function parameter lists. Now let's look at the definition of `DDirectory::foo()`:

```
template<class arg,class conv>
struct DDirectory : public virtual Directory<arg,conv>, public virtual DFile<arg,conv>{
    void foo(typename conv::Directory::UnionType& d){
    }
};
```

In the instantiation `DDirectory<int,thing>` `conv` is `FSU<int,DFS,DFS>`, so instantiation of it involves instantiation of `UnionBase`s inside, and eventially to this:

```
static_assert(AllInheritFrom<Base,Rest...>::value, "All of the elements of UnionBase must have Base as a public base");
```

where one of classes is `DDirectory<int,thing>`. Remember, all this happens in the deducing the type of the parameter of `foo()`, so `DDirectory<int,thing>` is incomplete, and that's what the compiler is saying.

You could try to move that `static_assert` for example to the constructor of `UnionBase`, but it doesn't solve other error which I think is impossible to fix, and the reason is the same:

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'DDirectory<int, FSU<int, DFS, DFS> >'
static const bool FirstBigger = sizeof(First) > sizeof(Best);
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is a minimized example reproducing the problem:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct BiggerType {
    using type = typename std::conditional<(sizeof(T1) > sizeof(T2)), T1, T2>::type;
};

template<typename T>
struct S {
    using B = BiggerType<S, int>;

    // This causes the instantiation of BiggerType,
    // leading to calculation of sizeof(S) which is incomplete
    void foo(const typename B::type& bt) {
    }
};

int main() {
    S<int> s;
}
```

Or in very compressed form,

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    // Same problem here
    void foo(typename std::conditional<(sizeof(S) > sizeof(int)), S, int>::type&) {
    }
};
```